# Auto scan or manual capture in ID verification case

Tags: photos

The case is to verify users' ID documents (ID, drivers licence, passport) via smartphone. The goal is to get a clear and sharp photo of their ID for this step.

We currently can do 2 options:

A. auto scan, which records a range of photos when they pointing the camera to their ID and the AI selects the best shot to verify, which takes half a sec.

B. we can do the traditional 1 button camera shot to capture the single shot. We add a confirm window asking whether the photo is clear and sharp. And then the photo is uploaded.

Should I use the auto scan or manual capture?
What are the best practices?

Comment: Can you please provide more details about the specific use case? What is the project that you're working on, and what do we know about the user and their needs?

Comment: Thanks for the comment. now I added more context about this issue.

Comment: With option A, who will be selecting the best shot? Is it the user, or will the photos be sent to your end and a member of you support team will choose the best one?

Comment: Also, thanks for the additional information, I have retracted my close vote and removed my initial comment. I have to say, I wish more new users were as willing to provide extra information as your are :D

Comment: Actually the AI will choose the best shot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should lean towards option B.

Put the onus on the user to take one single clear photo that shows the information you need. Make sure to have a "help" section that details what the photo needs to include to be classified as valid, to help reduce invalid photos sent your way.

In terms of work flow, you should look at something like this:

- User is prompted to take a photo of an ID document. Ensure to include a link for further information that details what types of ID documents are accepted, and what information they need to include. Emphasise the importance of a clear/sharp photo. Allow review of photo (as per your suggestion in question)
- User "submits" a single photo and the process is put into a "pending" state. Inform the user that the ID document is pending review and they will be notified once reviewed.
- At your end, have a feature that allows a support team member the ability to review and process pending documents. This internal user should have two options: approve and reject.
- If approved, the end-user will get a notification that their ID is accepted. At this point, you can remove any account restrictions that might be in place pending a valid ID (if any).
- If rejected, notify the end-user and provide information about why it was rejected. Give them the ability to provide another photo that addresses the concerns. Repeat this process until a photo is approved.

---

**UPDATE**

In response to your comment:

> Actually the AI will choose the best shot.

In this case, follow the same steps as above, but replace "support team member" with your AI function. The process should still be the same.

If the AI is fast enough, you can skip step 2 about notifying the user of the pending review. Just jump straight to the approved/rejected notifications.